# Not able to communicate with server after enabling Perfect Forward Secrecy and Disable Weak Ciphers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, security, response

My website is hosted on a server..I am getting response from the website url by following code in my c# application using .net framework 4 client profile.

```
string url = "www.mywebsite.com/update/abc.txt";

HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

myRequest.Method = "GET";

WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
```

I was getting response easily.

But for security reason i enabled Perfect Forward Secrecy and Disable Weak Ciphers. After this i am not getting any response using this code. I am getting following error...

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream.

Should i change the code for getting response after enabling Perfect Forward Secrecy.

Comment: Use an IE to get to site and see if it works.  If it does use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare IE with your application.  To get HttpWebRequest to work you have to add missing headers.  The IE automatically adds these headers and the request doesn't.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?view=netframework-4.7.2 You are targeting .NET 4, which obviously uses TLS 1.0 as default. If your plan to disable weak ciphers aims to upgrade to new TLS versions such as 1.2, follow the best practice guide carefully (read every words of it).